# Hit counts for eCommerce tracking in Google Analytics (Universal Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

According to what I can tell from Google's documentation, discreet hitTypes like pageview, event, and social all count against your "hit" budget. But with eCommerce, it looks like a hitType called "transaction" is sent first, followed by a number of "item" hitTypes. Do each one of these "item" hitTypes count against the budget, or are they included with the single "transaction" hitType.

If anyone knows for absolute certain, I would be most appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en specifies 10 mio hits as data limit. The [Google TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) in their first paragraph specify that an item is a hit ("**A Hit may currently be a**[n] page view, a transaction, **item**, or event"). So they count towards the limit.